# After I install mamba with conda , I have this problem :Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

Tags: python, conda, mamba

[When using"conda install" command to install package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMrue.png)

[When using mamba command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0YfH.png)

Windows 11 , python 3.8.18, mamba 0.1.2

I guess that this error was caused by mamba. I want to uninstall it but when implement "conda remove  mamba" ,  I got the same problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZalG.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of error messages. Please copy paste the content of your terminal into your question instead.